# Tabularx Misplaced \noalign but used to work before?

Tags: lyx, align, tabularx

My table used to work before and all of a sudden I am having an error that says I misplaced \noalign when I changed some inputs into my tables.

Would someone please help me take a look at the code please ?

An example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYYYYYY @{}}   

\toprule   

\thead[lc]{Category }& \thead{Strategies}& {\thead{Annualized \\ Mean}} & {\thead{Annualized \\ Volatility}} & {\thead{Skew}} & {\thead{kurtosis}} & {\thead{Sharpe \\ Ratio}}

    \midrule   

    \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 3.18 &  3.84 & -0.26 & 20.06 & 0.00  \\   
                                & TSMOM(3,3) & 11.85 &  7.76 & -1.96 & 24.72 & 0.00  \\ \addlinespace  
    \multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 1.44 & 15.80  \\
    & 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 0 & 0.23 & 1.00\\

    & Top minus Bottom & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00\\ 

    \addlinespace

    \multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 0.29 & 1.00 \\
    & Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Highest Minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\   

\bottomrule 

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is simple typing error. Error message quit clear indicate, that `\midrule` you haven't command `end of line`.

Anyway that problem is allready solved by comments, I sugest you to check your preamble again. In it you have many dušlicates of definition, some are also wrong. SO, see my clean-up of your code belos:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X }% duplicate, wrong, missing \arraybackslash
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\Centering}X}% duplicate, wrong, missing \arraybackslash, 
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}% default settings is ok
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

    %\setlength\parindent{0pt}% duplicate
    %\setlength\parindent{0pt}% duplicate
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[margin=30mm,showframe]{geometry}% added for better column layout


\begin{document}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{5}{S[table-format=3.3]} @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[b]{Category}
    &   {\thead[b]{Strategies}}
        &   {\thead[b]{Annualized \\ Mean}} 
            &   {\thead[b]{Annualized \\ Volatility}} 
                &   {\thead[b]{Skew}} 
                    &   {\thead[b]{Kurtosis}} 
                        &   {\thead[b]{Sharpe \\ Ratio}}   \\
\midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 3.18 &  3.84 & -0.26 & 20.06 & 0.00  \\
                                & TSMOM(3,3) & 11.85 &  7.76 & -1.96 & 24.72 & 0.00  \\ \addlinespace
    \multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 1.44 & 15.80  \\
    & 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 0 & 0.23 & 1.00\\
    & Top minus Bottom & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00\\
\addlinespace
    \multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 0.29 & 1.00 \\
    & Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Highest Minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]