# Advice for making this tabularx look nicer on a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, tabularx

I have the following slide:

[image]

With the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{G}{@{}>{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}l<{\end{lrbox}}@{}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[round,sort,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=40]{Summary Statistics}     \vspace*{2em}     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYYYYYY @{}}   
    \toprule   
\thead[lc]{Category }& \thead{Strategies}& {\thead{Annualized \\ Mean}} & {\thead{Volatility}} & {\thead{Skew}} & {\thead{kurtosis}} & {\thead{Sharpe \\ Ratio}} \\
    \midrule   
    \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 3.18 &  3.84 & -0.26 & 20.06 & 0.00  \\                                    &                                     TSMOM(3,3) & 11.85 &  7.76 & -1.96 & 24.72 & 0.00  \\ \addlinespace       
\multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 15.80 & 0.00 \\     
& 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.00\\     
& Bottom Decile & 8.96 & 5.07 & -0.57 & -9.38 & 0.00 \\     
& 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 10.13 & 5.19 & -0.44 & 10.87 & 0.00\\
& Top minus Bottom & 3.75 & 6.54 & 2.45 & 18.54 & 0.00\\ \addlinespace

\multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 11.76 & 8.73 & 0.1915 & 14.62 & 0.00\\     
& Bottom Decile & 8.38 & 5.76 & -0.59 & 8.74 & 0.00 \\     
& Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 3.38 & 5.94 & 0.68 & 11.03 & 0.00 \\     
& Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 11.79 & 8.73 & 0.19 & 14.62 & 0.00 \\     
& Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 10.04 & 5.64 & 0.03 & 13.76 & 0.00 \\     
& Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 9.04 & 5.43 & -0.73 & 8.80 & 0.00 \\     
& Highest Minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} & 2.72 & 5.60 & 0.82 & 12.79 & 0.00 \\   

\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, the slide texts feels quite squished for the 2nd column. Also, the last row has some text that is being cut off. Is there anyways to fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: Too much information for a single slide.  I would suggest 5 slides with the mean through the ratio each on a separate slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use my answer on similar your question ( [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297254/tabularx-misplaced-noalign-but-used-to-work-before)) and play little bit with `[shrink=<amount>]`, you will able to achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=30]{Summary Statistics}     
    \vspace*{2em}     
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{5}{S[table-format=3.3]} @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[b]{Category}
    &   {\thead[b]{Strategies}}
        &   {\thead[b]{Annualized \\ Mean}}
            &   {\thead[b]{Annualized \\ Volatility}}
                &   {\thead[b]{Skew}}
                    &   {\thead[b]{Kurtosis}}
                        &   {\thead[b]{Sharpe \\ Ratio}}   \\
\midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 3.18 &  3.84 & -0.26 & 20.06 & 0.00  \\
                                & TSMOM(3,3) & 11.85 &  7.76 & -1.96 & 24.72 & 0.00  \\ \addlinespace
    \multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 1.44 & 15.80  \\
    & 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 0 & 0.23 & 1.00\\
    & Top minus Bottom & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00\\
\addlinespace
    \multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 0.29 & 1.00 \\
    & Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
    & Highest Minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} & 0 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I ran into this trouble but didnt want to bother you for asking too much but it looks like you ran into it again. Once again, thank you very much

Comment: Its OK, however, if you already receive an answer, close to your needs, than for some new requirements use it for starting point. With this you will (i) learn more about (table) typesetting in LaTeX and probably find solutions yourself, (ii) make people here his their help easier. Happy TeX-ing!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 5):

My advice (as the author of the package) is never use `tabularx` for data tables. It s designed to affect linebreaking widths in columns, but you have no linebreaking here. the numeric columns would look better if the y were aligned on the decimal point using a D column from `dcolumn` or an S column from `siunitx`. And don't take two lines for your row headings, it introduces ugly gaps.
So something like this

[image]

Although as there is some vertical space left I'd probably add more space between the groups.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{G}{@{}>{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}l<{\end{lrbox}}@{}}

\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[round,sort,comma]{natbib}
\newcommand\thead[1]{\textbf{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=40]{Summary Statistics}  
\centering
\vspace*{2em}     
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll
*{5}{S} @{}}   
    \toprule   
\thead{Category }& \thead{Strategies}& {\thead{Annualized \\ Mean}} & {\thead{Volatility}} & {\thead{Skew}} & {\thead{kurtosis}} & {\thead{Sharpe \\ Ratio}} \\
    \midrule   
Momentum  & TSMOM(1,1) & 3.18 &  3.84 & -0.26 & 20.06 & 0.00  \\                                    &                                     TSMOM(3,3) & 11.85 &  7.76 & -1.96 & 24.72 & 0.00  \\ \addlinespace       
Size  & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 15.80 & 0.00 \\     
& 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.00\\     
& Bottom Decile & 8.96 & 5.07 & -0.57 & -9.38 & 0.00 \\     
& 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 10.13 & 5.19 & -0.44 & 10.87 & 0.00\\
& Top minus Bottom & 3.75 & 6.54 & 2.45 & 18.54 & 0.00\\ \addlinespace

Value  & Top Decile & 11.76 & 8.73 & 0.1915 & 14.62 & 0.00\\     
& Bottom Decile & 8.38 & 5.76 & -0.59 & 8.74 & 0.00 \\     
& Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 3.38 & 5.94 & 0.68 & 11.03 & 0.00 \\     
& Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 11.79 & 8.73 & 0.19 & 14.62 & 0.00 \\     
& Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 10.04 & 5.64 & 0.03 & 13.76 & 0.00 \\     
& Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 9.04 & 5.43 & -0.73 & 8.80 & 0.00 \\     
& Highest Minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} & 2.72 & 5.60 & 0.82 & 12.79 & 0.00 \\   

\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```